# How to add space with continuous long string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add space with continuously long string if there is no space in string after certain characters using JavaScript

For example string is

> Helocsdnsajdnsajndjksandjks addwdwdwdnsajkkwfjnwkjqnf
>   wkjnfkjewnfefewfefewdd

and we want space after 10 characters

Result should be

> Helocsdnsa jdnsajndjk sandjks addwdwdwdn sajkkwfjnw kjqnf wkjnfkjewn
>   fefewfefew dd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `/([^ ]{10})/g` with `.replace()` method to add space after every 10 characters. Try this:

```js
var str = "Helocsdnsajdnsajndjksandjks addwdwdwdnsajkkwfjnwkjqnf wkjnfkjewnfefewfefewdd";
str = str.replace(/([^ ]{10})/g, "$1 ");
console.log(str)
```

Comment: How can we put that code spinet in a function and pass 10 as parameter and join it to regular expression ?

Answer (score 1):

This can also do the job. If someone can do more customization to it, this code can help...

```
function SplitString(str, charLimit) {
    var arrData = str.split(" ");
    var returnStr = '';
    if (arrData.length > 0) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) 
        {
            if (arrData[i].length > charLimit) 
            {
                var element = arrData[i];
                var element2 = '';
                var loopTimes = Math.ceil(arrData[i].length / charLimit);
                var pickPlace = 0                

                for(var j = 0;j<loopTimes;j++) 
                {
                    if (j == (loopTimes - 1)) {

                        element2 = element2 + element.substring(pickPlace, element.length);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        element2 = element2 + element.substring(pickPlace, (pickPlace + charLimit)) + ' ';
                    }
                    pickPlace = pickPlace + charLimit;
                }
                arrData[i] = element2;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) 
        {
            returnStr = returnStr + arrData[i] + ' ';
        }
        returnStr = returnStr.substring(0,returnStr.length-1);
        return returnStr;
    }
}
```